# Интеграция Google Pay и Apple Pay в приложение flutter

Tags: flutter, платежи, google-pay

Кто может подсказать как интегрировать Google/Apple Pay в приложение на flutter. Суть в том что мне нужно добавить меню выбора карт, и получить google_pay_token/apple_pay_token что бы потом отправить этот токен в IPAY для оплаты услуг. Не могу найти нормальною документацией в которой бы пошагово было написано как интегрировать это в приложение. Попробовал использовать библиотеку https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pay но она постоянно пишет ошибку что такого продавца нет в системе Google Pay(хотя он есть) а иногда пишет ошибку: "На стороне разработчика произошла ошибка. Повторите попытку позже". Кто может подсказать как такое реализовать или где можно почитать нормальную инструкцию, т.к. я ничего хорошего не нашел. Буду очень благодарен за дельный совет. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делал pull requests в эту библиотек и проверял её в боевом режиме (полностью работает). Возьмите исходники из [GitHub](https://github.com/xamelon/flutter_pay):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_pay:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/xamelon/flutter_pay.git
```

[Как использовать](https://github.com/xamelon/flutter_pay/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart):

```
FlutterPay flutterPay = FlutterPay()..setEnvironment(environment: PaymentEnvironment.Test);

...

flutterPay.requestPayment(
  googleParameters: GoogleParameters(
    gatewayName: "example", // обязательное поле
    gatewayMerchantId: "example_id",
  ),
  appleParameters: AppleParameters(
        merchantIdentifier: "merchant.flutterpay.example", // обязательное поле 
      ),
  currencyCode: "USD",
  countryCode: "US",
  paymentItems: items,
);
```

**Также у вас должны быть разрешения со стороны Google и Apple.**

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.